# visualizing the code for checking if a number is prime

Tags: python, function, loops, primes, visualize

In the below code, if we input 2, it displays it as a prime number. Can you please help me visualize how the loop works for input 2?

```
def prime_checker(number):
    is_prime = True
    for i in range(2, number):
        if (i % number == 0):
            is_prime = False
    if is_prime:
        print(f"The {number} is a prime number")
    else:
        print(f"The {number} is not a prime number")
number = int(input("Enter the number that you want to check: "))
prime_checker(number)
```

I tried to visualize it but i still have that doubt.

Comment: You probably meant to write `number % i`, not `i % number`.

Comment: You never enter the `for` loop. By the way 2 is a prime number...

Comment: Check what `list(range(2,2))` returns. That is what you are iterating over in your for-loop, if number is 2.

Comment: Thx for the reply, got it now. There are open brackets so it's an empty sequence for (2,2) and thus it goes to the second if loop.